# Looping on aggregate function

Tags: r, for-loop, aggregate-functions

I have a dataframe, df = (Var1,Day,Month,Years). I need to run a significance test for each year's data. But the arguments that need to be passed to the function (in this case,a significance test) are in another data frame. I use the following code, but I do not get the correct results. [where param1 and param2 are vectors with parameters for each year]

```
for (i in (no.of.years))    
{
  result_stat <- aggregate(Var1~YY,df,function(X)ks.test(X,'pgamma',shape = param1[i], rate = param2[i]))
}
```

Could you please let me know whats wrong with my for loop? When the same step is performed separately without the loop [i.e., get each years data manually and pass the arguments param1 and param2 hard-coded] I get a different set of outcomes.

Comment: First, you need to use `[` to access vector elements, so modify `param1(i)` to `param1[i]` (and same for `param2`). Also `result_stat` is overwritten in each iteration, you need to define it as a list and then assign the result of each iteration to `result_stat[[i]]`. To get more help please provide info so your problem is reproducible, and more details on the error(s) you get.

Comment: First one was a typo. I do not get any error, but I get incorrect test statistic.I think the problem is 'i' within the function which in turn is inside aggregate.

Comment: I don't think there would be a problem with `i`, it should get passed to the function fine. Another guess of what the problem may be is that you want to use aggregate only on the subset of data that contains a specific year but you are doing it for all years? What are `Var1` and `YY` exactly in `aggregate`, do you have a data frame attached or something?

Comment: Var1 is daily rainfall data. YY is years. I have 50 years of data and would like to run the goodness of fit (ks.test) for each year with specific parameters. I have these params for 50 years in another vector.

Comment: I need the for loop only to increment the value of 'i' in param1 and param2. But aggregate function seems to run the function (for all the years) within a single iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are running `aggregate` on the whole data instead of a subset for a given year. Since you are not giving more info on your data I will assume that it looks like this

```
df 
#       Var1   YY Month Day
#   7.896072 2000     1   1
#  11.881620 2000     2   2
#  12.315676 2000     3   3
#   7.459200 2010     1  10
#  10.944619 2010     2  11
#  11.371278 2010     3  12
```

and your parameters are in a another data frame, as you say

```
params
#  YY   param1 param2
#  2000      1    0.1
#  2010      2    0.2
```

Since you are running a `for` loop over years, you don't need to `aggregate`; just take the subset of `df` for each year

```
years <- unique(df$YY)
result_stat <- vector("list", length(years))
names(result_stat) <- years
for (i in seq_along(years)) {
    y <- years[[i]]
    result_stat[[i]] <- ks.test(df[df$YY == y, ]$Var1, "pgamma", 
        shape = params[params$YY == y, ]$param1,
        rate = params[params$YY == y, ]$param2)
}
```

Comment: It Worked!Did not know I could use df[df$YY == y, ]$Var1. Thanks!